# React-Native Async Storage returns weird object with correct value in two consecutive lines

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I've researched this and not found a similar case answered, at my whits end.

I have the following code to get an item from AsyncStorage, which returns the correct value when I log it on the console, but the function's return value is: `{\"_40\":0,\"_65\":1,\"_55\":\"Nick\",\"_72\":null}`

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userDetails');
        if(value !== null) {
            const wsi_user = await JSON.parse(value);
            console.log("userName: " + wsi_user.userName); // returns "Nick"
            return wsi_user.userName; // returns {\"_40\":0,\"_65\":1,\"_55\":\"Nick\",\"_72\":null}
        }
    } catch(e) {
        letter = "D";
    }
}
```

I've seen similar articles where people mention that the promise needs to resolve and I get that, but my result is within the outputted weird object, AND, my result is correct when logged to console the line before `return`.

Please advise. No clue how to fix this.

Comment: I get the same result when removing the `await` in front of `JSON.parse(value);`

Answer (score 1):

You can call this function like:

```
const result = await getData()
```

Also, you don't need the await before `JSON.parse()` as it is synchronous.

Comment: This didn't work at all. Not sure what is up. I get the same result as above.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md), through which you can access AsyncStorage synchronously, and can also store and retrieve objects, strings or Boolean data

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
  // or import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   export const RNStorage = { userInfo: undefined  };
   
  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
  };
  
  XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the object to a string before saving it in the async storage `AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));`

Example:

```
export const setStorageItem = async (key: string, data: any): Promise<void> => {
  return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
};

export const getStorageItem = async <T>(key: string): Promise<T | null> => {
  const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
  if (item) {
    return JSON.parse(item);
  }
  return null;
};
```

Example from the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/176812ec486323fe455cfbd8d008f635ad27f7e6/example/examples/MergeItem.js#L107)

Comment: I did save it as a string. That's why I'm confused, because that same piece of code has worked in another component - pulling another property from the"object".